# Some users' avatar have background shadow, some do not have

Tags: discussion

I find a minor detail:

[image]

some users' avatar have background shadow, some do not have.

whether this is decide by the reputation?

Comment: The 'about me' section must be filled (in addition to having 1k) for the shadow to appear.

Comment: You blurred the username, but I can still find the users by the title of the question.

Comment: @Glorfindel Hhhh... Thank you, I got it.

Comment: I now feel like Pan trying to get my shadow!

Comment: Why so careful about hiding usernames?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part of the [Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege:

> When anyone is viewing your usercard on a question, an answer, or on the users list, they may hover over your avatar to produce an expanded usercard that contains extra information. This is also known as a hover card.
>
> An expanded usercard is only available if there are at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile. When your profile is long enough to show an expanded usercard a drop shadow effect will be shown on your avatar.